# new RegExp('^\+\d{2}\.\d{10}$') doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to test a string's format. This string should start with a `+` sign, then 2 digits, then a `.` sign, then 10 digits.

```
/^\+\d{2}\.\d{10}$/.test('+34.2398320186');
```

This way, it works (you can test it). But when I use `RegExp`, it says that the syntax has **invalid quantifier** error. What's wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to escape the `\` with a second `\\`

```
new RegExp('^\\+\\d{2}\\.\\d{10}$'); // should work
```

I'll add a recommendation from http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

> I recommend that you do not use the RegExp constructor with a literal
>   string, because in literal strings, backslashes must be escaped.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're specifying the regex as a string, you also need to escape the '\', because that's also the string escape character. So you'd want:

```
new RegExp('^\\+\\d{2}\\.\\d{10}$');
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this if you don't want to escape backslash

```
var regex = /^\+\d{2}\.\d{10}$/ 
new RegExp(regex).test('+34.2398320186');
```

If you want to use string as param to RegExp then you have to escape the backslash.

Comment: Considering you already have a regular expression on line 1, why should you use the "constructor"?

Comment: @xanatos I am not sure what OP is doing, I just pointed out that it works fine when you use that particular constructor.